# JSON deserialize into wrapper class errors

Tags: apex, json, wrapper-class, deserialize

I'm trying to set up integration to display quiz answers in a Visualforce page, but I'm having a lot of difficulty deserializing a JSON string (supplied via API call response) into a wrapper class which seems to validate perfectly when I run it through http://jsonlint.com/ or http://json2apexengine.somee.com/ . The JSON string is pretty massive so I'm hoping I can get help without having to supply the whole thing.

Errors I'm getting in particular include:

> System.JSONException: Expected CanvasCourseController.event_data but
>   found [line:1, column:23954]

which I'm interpreting as there's some interruption to the expected json format

> System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('f' (code 102)): was
>   expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at [line:1, column:537]

which seems to be a result of html formatting in string values

> System.JSONException: Illegal unquoted character ((CTRL-CHAR, code
>   10)): has to be escaped using backslash to be included in string value
>   at [line:1, column:507]

a line break issue I've resolved using `string.replace('\n', ' ')`;

I created the wrapper class by running the json string through json2apexengine, it's as follows:

```
public class JsonParser{
        public list<quiz_submission_events> quiz_submission_events{get;set;}
    public class quiz_submission_events{
        public event_data event_data{get;set;}
        public String event_type{get;set;}
        public String created_at{get;set;}
        public String id{get;set;}
    }
    public class quiz_data{
        public String question_type{get;set;}
        public String question_name{get;set;}
        public String neutral_comments_html{get;set;}
        public String name{get;set;}
        public String incorrect_comments_html{get;set;}
        public String question_text{get;set;}
        public String correct_comments_html{get;set;}
        public list<answers> answers{get;set;}
        public String neutral_comments{get;set;}
        public String text_after_answers{get;set;}
        public String incorrect_comments{get;set;}
        public Integer assessment_question_id{get;set;}
        public String correct_comments{get;set;}
        public Integer position{get;set;}
        public Integer points_possible{get;set;}
        public String published_at{get;set;}
        public String regrade_option{get;set;}
        public Integer id{get;set;}
    }
    public class event_data{
        public list<quiz_data> quiz_data{get;set;}
        public Integer quiz_version{get;set;}
    }
    public class answers{
        public String answer_weight{get;set;}
        public String match_id{get;set;}
        public String answer_text{get;set;}
        public String id{get;set;}
        public String answer_match_left{get;set;}
        public String blank_id{get;set;}
        public String answer_match_right{get;set;}
        public String numerical_answer_type{get;set;}
        public String answer_comment{get;set;}
        public String answer_range_end{get;set;}
        public String answer_html{get;set;}
        public String answer_range_start{get;set;}
        public String answer_match_left_html{get;set;}
        public String answer_error_margin{get;set;}
        public String answer_comment_html{get;set;}
        public String answer_exact{get;set;}
    }
}
```

Here's an excerpt of the JSON:

```
{
    "quiz_submission_events": [
        {
            "id": "4629",
            "event_type": "submission_created",
            "event_data": {
                "quiz_version": 21,
                "quiz_data": [
                    {
                        "id": 220,
                        "regrade_option": "",
                        "points_possible": 0,
                        "correct_comments": "",
                        "incorrect_comments": "",
                        "neutral_comments": "",
                        "correct_comments_html": "",
                        "incorrect_comments_html": "",
                        "neutral_comments_html": "",
                        "question_type": "text_only_question",
                        "question_name": "Spacer",
                        "name": "Spacer",
                        "question_text": "<p><strong>Read the advertisement below and answer the questions that follow.</strong></p>\n<p> </p>\n<p><em><span style=\"font-size: 14pt;\"><strong>Grand Opening this Saturday 27<sup>th</sup> June!</strong></span></em></p>\n<p><strong>769 Asperity Road, Mt. Falls</strong></p>\n<p><strong>Gates Open 9:00am to 4:00pm</strong></p>\n<p> </p>\n<p><strong><img src=\"/courses/34/files/2325/preview\" alt=\"Koala.png\"><span style=\"font-size: 18pt;\">Salvation Animal Sanctuary</span></strong></p>\n<p><strong>                        Come to our opening and support the </strong><strong>rescue of native animals.</strong></p>\n<p><strong>                        Visit our Educational Display Centre, </strong><strong>Souvenir Shop and Café.</strong></p>\n<p><strong> </strong></p>\n<p><strong>The grand opening will have rides for children </strong><strong>and games to play.</strong></p>\n<p><strong> </strong></p>\n<p><strong>As bad weather can cause some of the  </strong><strong>animals to be reclusive, the Sanctuary staff will </strong><strong>be at many of the enclosures to bring the animals </strong><strong>closer and answer any questions.</strong></p>\n<p>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       </p>\n<table style=\"height: 140px;\" width=\"328\"><tbody><tr>\n<td>\n<p><strong>Sanctuary Entry Prices</strong></p>\n<p>Adults $10.00              Children (Under 16) $5.00</p>\nDonations to support the society can be made at the zoo office or by calling 1300 555                      </td>\n</tr></tbody></table><p>                                                                                </p>\n<p> <img src=\"/courses/34/files/2326/preview\" alt=\"Kangaroo.png\">           </p>\n<p><strong>About us </strong>Salvation Animals Sanctuary is the brainchild of David Wright, founder of the Native Animal Rescue Society The self-sustaining Sanctuary was established help support the society in its rescue efforts. The Sanctuary is open to the public every Friday to Tuesday and welcomes all native animals who are in need of care and a home.</p>",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "answer_exact": "",
                                "answer_error_margin": "",
                                "answer_range_start": "",
                                "answer_range_end": "",
                                "answer_weight": "0",
                                "numerical_answer_type": "exact_answer",
                                "blank_id": "",
                                "id": "",
                                "match_id": "",
                                "answer_text": "",
                                "answer_match_left": "",
                                "answer_match_right": "",
                                "answer_comment": "",
                                "answer_html": "",
                                "answer_match_left_html": "",
                                "answer_comment_html": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "answer_exact": "",
                                "answer_error_margin": "",
                                "answer_range_start": "",
                                "answer_range_end": "",
                                "answer_weight": "0",
                                "numerical_answer_type": "exact_answer",
                                "blank_id": "",
                                "id": "",
                                "match_id": "",
                                "answer_text": "",
                                "answer_match_left": "",
                                "answer_match_right": "",
                                "answer_comment": "",
                                "answer_html": "",
                                "answer_match_left_html": "",
                                "answer_comment_html": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "answer_exact": "",
                                "answer_error_margin": "",
                                "answer_range_start": "",
                                "answer_range_end": "",
                                "answer_weight": "0",
                                "numerical_answer_type": "exact_answer",
                                "blank_id": "",
                                "id": "",
                                "match_id": "",
                                "answer_text": "",
                                "answer_match_left": "",
                                "answer_match_right": "",
                                "answer_comment": "",
                                "answer_html": "",
                                "answer_match_left_html": "",
                                "answer_comment_html": ""
                            },
                            {
                                "answer_exact": "",
                                "answer_error_margin": "",
                                "answer_range_start": "",
                                "answer_range_end": "",
                                "answer_weight": "0",
                                "numerical_answer_type": "exact_answer",
                                "blank_id": "",
                                "id": "",
                                "match_id": "",
                                "answer_text": "",
                                "answer_match_left": "",
                                "answer_match_right": "",
                                "answer_comment": "",
                                "answer_html": "",
                                "answer_match_left_html": "",
                                "answer_comment_html": ""
                            }
                        ],
                        "text_after_answers": "",
                        "assessment_question_id": 264,
                        "position": 0,
                        "published_at": "2015-09-08T00:44:05Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 221,
                        "regrade_option": "",
                        "points_possible": 0,
                        "correct_comments": "",
                        "incorrect_comments": "",
                        "neutral_comments": "",
                        "correct_comments_html": "",
                        "incorrect_comments_html": "",
                        "neutral_comments_html": "",
                        "question_type": "multiple_answers_question",
                        "question_name": "Question 1",
                        "name": "Question 1",
                        "question_text": "blah",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "id": "878",
                                "text": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100,
                                "html": "<p>Cafe</p>"
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "959",
                                "text": "Office",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "9381",
                                "text": "Rides",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "812",
                                "text": "Games",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "3712",
                                "text": "Souvenir Shop",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "id": "7992",
                                "text": "Educational Centre",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100
                            }
                        ],
                        "text_after_answers": "",
                        "assessment_question_id": 265,
                        "position": 1,
                        "published_at": "2015-09-08T00:44:05Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 224,
                        "regrade_option": "",
                        "points_possible": 0,
                        "correct_comments": "",
                        "incorrect_comments": "",
                        "neutral_comments": "",
                        "correct_comments_html": "",
                        "incorrect_comments_html": "",
                        "neutral_comments_html": "",
                        "question_type": "multiple_choice_question",
                        "question_name": "Question 2",
                        "name": "Question 2",
                        "question_text": "blah",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "id": 6044,
                                "text": "To promote native animal rescue",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 7455,
                                "text": "To ask for donations for the sanctuary",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 9010,
                                "text": "To inform the public of the cost of entry",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 9910,
                                "text": "To advertise the opening of the sanctuary",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100
                            }
                        ],
                        "text_after_answers": "",
                        "assessment_question_id": 268,
                        "position": 2,
                        "published_at": "2015-09-08T00:44:05Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 225,
                        "regrade_option": "",
                        "points_possible": 0,
                        "correct_comments": "",
                        "incorrect_comments": "",
                        "neutral_comments": "",
                        "correct_comments_html": "",
                        "incorrect_comments_html": "",
                        "neutral_comments_html": "",
                        "question_type": "multiple_choice_question",
                        "question_name": "Question 3",
                        "name": "Question 3",
                        "question_text": "blah",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "id": 1462,
                                "text": "Withdrawn",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 4914,
                                "text": "Sociable",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 5670,
                                "text": "Unfriendly",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 454,
                                "text": "Drenched",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "text_after_answers": "",
                        "assessment_question_id": 269,
                        "position": 3,
                        "published_at": "2015-09-08T00:44:05Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 226,
                        "regrade_option": "",
                        "points_possible": 0,
                        "correct_comments": "",
                        "incorrect_comments": "",
                        "neutral_comments": "",
                        "correct_comments_html": "",
                        "incorrect_comments_html": "",
                        "neutral_comments_html": "",
                        "question_type": "multiple_choice_question",
                        "question_name": "Question 4",
                        "name": "Question 4",
                        "question_text": "<p>What is the purpose of David Wright’s brainchild?</p>",
                        "answers": [
                            {
                                "id": 6557,
                                "text": "To support the Native Animal Rescue Zoo",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 1937,
                                "text": "To support the Native Animal Rescue Society",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 100
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 8553,
                                "text": "To give the rescued animals a permanent home",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            },
                            {
                                "id": 3563,
                                "text": "To create a self-sustainable tourist attraction for Mt Falls",
                                "html": "",
                                "comments": "",
                                "comments_html": "",
                                "weight": 0
                            }
                        ],
                        "text_after_answers": "",
                        "assessment_question_id": 270,
                        "position": 4,
                        "published_at": "2015-09-08T00:44:05Z"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 227,
                        "regrade_option": "",
                        "points_possible": 0,
                        "correct_comments": "",
                        "incorrect_comments": "",
                        "neutral_comments": "",
                        "correct_comments_html": "",
                        "incorrect_comments_html": "",
                        "neutral_comments_html": "",
                        "question_type": "text_only_question",
                        "question_name": "Spacer",
                        "name": "Spacer",
                        "question_text": "blah",
                        "answers": [],
                        "text_after_answers": "",
                        "assessment_question_id": null,
                        "position": 4,
                        "published_at": "2015-09-08T00:44:05Z"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "created_at": "2015-09-30T01:02:34Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "4630",
            "event_type": "session_started",
            "event_data": {
                "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
            },
            "created_at": "2015-09-30T01:02:37Z"
        },
        {
            "id": "4631",
            "event_type": "question_answered",
            "event_data": [
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "220",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "221",
                    "answer": []
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "224",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "225",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "226",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "227",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "228",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "229",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "231",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "235",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "236",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "237",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "238",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "239",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "242",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "243",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "245",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "246",
                    "answer": null
                }
            ],
            "created_at": "2015-09-30T01:02:48Z"
        }
    ]
}
```

My main questions are:

1. Why is `JSON.deserialize` spitting the dummy on any of this if the
   above sites say it's valid?
2. Is there a method or efficient bit of code I can use to remove the
   troublesome characters?
3. What's causing the `event_data` parsing error?

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regarding the `event_data` issue: your JSON is inconsistent.  In one case it's an object containing the `user_agent` string:

```
"event_data": {
                "user_agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36"
            },
```

And elsewhere it's a list of `quiz_data`:

```
"event_data": [
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "220",
                    "answer": null
                },
                {
                    "quiz_question_id": "221",
                    "answer": []
                } [...]
            ],
```

This wouldn't be picked up by a JSON linter, because it's just checking that the data is *valid* - not that it's *consistent*.

I notice that the parser code generated by [JSON2Apex](http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) is different from your parser code above, and e.g. creates different classes to handle the different types of `answers` and `event_data`:

```
//
// Generated by JSON2Apex http://json2apex.herokuapp.com/
//

public class JSON2Apex {

    public class Answers {
        public String answer_exact;
        public String answer_error_margin;
        public String answer_range_start;
        public String answer_range_end;
        public String answer_weight;
        public String numerical_answer_type;
        public String blank_id;
        public String id;
        public String match_id;
        public String answer_text;
        public String answer_match_left;
        public String answer_match_right;
        public String answer_comment;
        public String answer_html;
        public String answer_match_left_html;
        public String answer_comment_html;
    }

    public class Quiz_data {
        public Integer id;
        public String regrade_option;
        public Integer points_possible;
        public String correct_comments;
        public String incorrect_comments;
        public String neutral_comments;
        public String correct_comments_html;
        public String incorrect_comments_html;
        public String neutral_comments_html;
        public String question_type;
        public String question_name;
        public String name;
        public String question_text;
        public List<Answers> answers;
        public String text_after_answers;
        public Integer assessment_question_id;
        public Integer position;
        public String published_at;
    }

    public class Answers_Z {
        public String id;
        public String text;
        public String comments;
        public String comments_html;
        public Integer weight;
        public String html;
    }

    public class Quiz_submission_events {
        public String id;
        public String event_type;
        public Event_data event_data;
        public String created_at;
    }

    public List<Quiz_submission_events> quiz_submission_events;

    public class Event_data {
        public Integer quiz_version;
        public List<Quiz_data> quiz_data;
    }

    public class Answers_Y {
        public Integer id;
        public String text;
        public String html;
        public String comments;
        public String comments_html;
        public Integer weight;
    }

    public class Answers_X {
    }

    public class Event_data_Z {
        public String user_agent;
    }

    public class Event_data_Y {
        public String quiz_question_id;
        public Object answer;
    }


    public static JSON2Apex parse(String json) {
        return (JSON2Apex) System.JSON.deserialize(json, JSON2Apex.class);
    }
}
```

This is an attempt to handle the inconsistencies in the JSON.  I'm not sure whether it'll actually work in practice, but it's worth trying.

If it doesn't work, you have a few options.

- Ideally you would change the JSON to be consistent, but that may not be an option if you're receiving it from a third party.
- Alternatively, you could use `JSON.deserializeUntyped()` and check the type of each `event_data` at runtime, but you'd lose the advantages of typed deserialization.
- Or, you could write custom parser code to manually check the value of `event_data` and parse it appropriately.  If you check the `Create explicit parse code` box on JSON2Apex, you can take the parser code as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it set me down the path of trying to understand json structure better. Looking at http://opfocus.com/blog/json-deserialization-techniques-in-salesforce/ I should be able to handle the inconsistent JSON through including every data data member/key event_data uses, as the deserializer should skip any data members not found in each event_data instance. I've tried this by adding String user_agent, Integer quiz_question_id and list<integer> answer but it's still throwing "Expected CanvasCourseController.event_data".

Comment: [cont.]Two problems I can see: 1) there are instances of event_data.answer that come back with [] and other instances that return null, not sure how to handle this. 2) Some instances of event data just contain arrays of integers with no key (e.g. "event_data":["242","243","245","246"]), not sure how to set up a wrapper class to handle this. I'm hoping I can set the wrapper class up properly to just use JSON.deserialize and handle the inconsistencies. Can this be done?