# System.JSONException: Unexpected character ('0' (code 48)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries at

Tags: apex, visualforce, json

This is my apex code

```
public PageReference find() {         

    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
    Http http = new Http();

    String url = 'http://clozer.3spire.net/public/user/'+strTag+'/'+cities;

    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    //these parts of the POST you may want to customize
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setBody('key1=value1&key2=value2');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  

    try {
        res = http.send(req);       
    } catch(System.CalloutException e) {
        system.debug('Callout error: '+ e);
        //result = ''+e;
    }    

    data = (Map<String, Result>)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(),Map<String, Result>.class);

    lstResultWrapper = new List<ResultWrapper>();
    for(Result obj: data.values())
    {      
      lstResultWrapper.add(new ResultWrapper(obj));
    }

        return null;
    }     

public class Result
{
    public String description {get;set;}
    public String person_name {get;set;}
    public String email {get;set;}
    public String exparience {get;set;}
    public String location {get;set;}
}

public class ResultWrapper{

 public Result objResult {get;set;}
 public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}

 public ResultWrapper(Result objResult){
   this.objResult = objResult;
   isSelected = false;
 }    
}
```

Json string is

```
{"0":{"description ":"","person_name":"Justin Townsley","email":"jlt@staranchor.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"1":{"description ":"","person_name":"Dan Anderson","email":"danandersonmobile@yahoo.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"2":{"description ":"","person_name":"Artak Robert Melkonyan","email":"artakrobert@gmail.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"3":{"description ":"","person_name":"Sanjay Anandaram","email":"sanjayanandaram@gmail.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"4":{"description ":"","person_name":"Katia Gaika","email":"katia.gaika@gmail.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"5":{"description ":"","person_name":"Sidnei Gon\u008dalves","email":"sidnei.goncalves@up2place.com.br","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"6":{"description ":"","person_name":"Michel Koch","email":"michelkoch@hotmail.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"7":{"description ":"","person_name":"Shannon Lydell Carter, MBA Technolo","email":"Shannon@truegame.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"8":{"description ":"","person_name":"Jacob Hagemann","email":"jhagemann@gmail.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"},"9":{"description ":"","person_name":"Amaresh Ramaswamy","email":"amareshr@live.com","exparience":null,"location":"Unknown"}}
```

Why this error is happening and how to get ride of this.Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does your response look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON deserialize into wrapper class errors](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/94260/json-deserialize-into-wrapper-class-errors)

Comment: {"s":1,"v":{"0":{"email":"jlt@staranchor.com","location":"Unknown","person_name":"Justin Townsley"}}}

is this what you ask for

Comment: than how can i solved it.I saw that post but not understand anyway

Comment: That JSON response you sent fails in JSON lint, is that accurate?

Comment: that i found that from developer console.if you visite this http://clozer.3spire.net/public/user/Business%20activities/65291 line you'll see the real json respose

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35087/discussion-between-moin-khan-and-ericssh).

Comment: In chat for a little if you want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So After discussion with moin. We found issue.

After debugging the issue. I found the reason, **issue in end point url**

for example `strTag = Business activities` then we need to replace space between Business and activities with `%20`.

After replacing this it worked like charm..

Issue related to end point..

```
String url = 'http://clozer.3spire.net/public/user/'+strTag+'/'+cities;
```

AFter changing this to

```
String url = 'http://clozer.3spire.net/public/user/'+strTag.replaceAll(' ', '%20')+'/'+cities;
```

it worked...

---

I Know if we used `Business activities` without %20 then it wil automatically changed the space to %20 but it didn't worked...

Noted:- We tried using `EncodingUtil.urlEncode(strTag, 'UTF-8')` but in url encoding space replace with + so that the reason it didn't worked.

Answer (score 1):

After looking at this closer and running it my execute anon you are getting a bad json response..

`01:42:33:604 USER_DEBUG [24]|DEBUG|res.getBody(){"0":{"description ":"none","person_name":"none","email":"none","exparience":"none,"location":"none"}}`

Notice that

```
 "exparience":"none,"location"
```

is not a valid json string and you won't be able to deserialize that, I recommend checking that out first..

Here is the code that I was running for it, fix the end point

```
  HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
Http http = new Http();
string strTag = 'Businessactivities';
String url = 'http://clozer.3spire.net/public/user/'+EncodingUtil.urlEncode(strTag, 'UTF-8')+'/65291';
CitiesResult result = new CitiesResult();
    req.setEndpoint(url);
    req.setMethod('GET');

    //these parts of the POST you may want to customize
    req.setCompressed(false);
    req.setBody('{"s":1,"v":{"0":{"email":"jlt@staranchor.com","location":"Unknown","person_name"‌:"Justin Townsley"}}}');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');  

    try {
        res = http.send(req);       
    } 
    catch(System.CalloutException e) 
    {
        system.debug('Callout error: '+ e);

    } 

String json = '{"0":{"description ":"","person_name":"Justin Townsley","email":"jlt@staranchor.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"1":{"description ":"","person_name":"Dan Anderson","email":"danandersonmobile@yahoo.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"2":{"description ":"","person_name":"Artak Robert Melkonyan","email":"artakrobert@gmail.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"3":{"description ":"","person_name":"Sanjay Anandaram","email":"sanjayanandaram@gmail.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"4":{"description ":"","person_name":"Katia Gaika","email":"katia.gaika@gmail.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"5":{"description ":"","person_name":"Sidnei Gon\u008dalves","email":"sidnei.goncalves@up2place.com.br","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"6":{"description ":"","person_name":"Michel Koch","email":"michelkoch@hotmail.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"7":{"description ":"","person_name":"Shannon Lydell Carter, MBA Technolo","email":"Shannon@truegame.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"8":{"description ":"","person_name":"Jacob Hagemann","email":"jhagemann@gmail.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"},"9":{"description ":"","person_name":"Amaresh Ramaswamy","email":"amareshr@live.com","exparience":"","location":"Unknown"}}';

System.debug('response code' + res.getStatusCode());
    System.debug('res.getBody()' + res.getBody());
    result = (CitiesResult)System.JSON.deserialize(json, CitiesResult.class);
System.debug('result' +result);

public class CitiesResult
{
    public CitiesResult(){}

    public String description {get;set;}
    public String person_name {get;set;}
    public String email {get;set;}
    public String exparience {get;set;}
    public String location {get;set;}
}

/* public class citiesResultWrapper{

 public Result objResult {get;set;}
 public Boolean isSelected {get;set;}

 public citiesResult(Result objResult){
   this.objResult = objResult;
   isSelected = false;
 }   
}*/
```